# In iOS/Swift, what module is MatrixHelper a part of?

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, opengl-es, arkit

I'm trying to follow some sample code https://medium.com/@yatchoi/getting-started-with-arkit-real-life-waypoints-1707e3cb1da2 below and I'm getting `unresolved identifier 'MatrixHelper'`

```
    let translationMatrix = MatrixHelper.translate(
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: distance * -1
    )
    // Rotation matrix theta degrees
    let rotationMatrix = MatrixHelper.rotateAboutY(
        degrees: bearing * -1
    )
```

What library or package do I need to import to get MatrixHelper - some Math package?  I googled the docs but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he just wrote a custom class to wrap the functions provided by GLKit.

He named that class MatrixHelper.

With MatrixHelper.rotateAboutY() he is calling something like:

```
GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4Rotate(GLKMatrix4 matrix, float radians, float x, float y, float z);
```

So the package used in MatrixHelper is GLKit and to be more precise GLKMatrix4

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkmatrix4-pce

Comment: I'd recommend against using GLKMatrix4 or the other GLKMath types unless you're interfacing with other GLKit API — Apple's newer `SIMD` library (`simd_float4x4` and related types) provides better performance and is directly supported by ARKit, SceneKit, and other high level frameworks. (Some wrapper code for matrix math conveniences would be nice for use with SIMD types, though.)

Comment: so how would we implement rotateAboutY using SIMD?

Comment: As far as I understand your tutorial link, he is constructing the matrix with glkit, because he is writing that he found little helper in glkit to construct the transform and rotation matrix. Under that line of code he is using simd_mul to apply those matrixes.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using MatrixHelper (also *GLKit*), use simd, it is simple. The methods would look the following way:

```
func getTranslationMatrix(tx: Float, ty: Float, tz: Float) -> simd_float4x4 {
    var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translationMatrix.columns.3 = simd_float4(tx, ty, tz, 1)
    return translationMatrix
}

func getRotationYMatrix(angle: Float) -> simd_float3x3 {
    let rows = [
        simd_float3(cos(angle), 0, -sin(angle)),
        simd_float3(0, 1, 0),
        simd_float3(-sin(angle), 0, cos(angle))
    ]
    return float3x3(rows: rows)
}
```

Or more specific the translation matrix:

```
func getTranslationZMatrix(tz: Float) -> simd_float4x4 {
    var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translationMatrix.columns.3.z = tz
    return translationMatrix
}
```

Then the code would look like:

```
func getTransformGiven(currentLocation: CLLocation) -> matrix_float4x4 {
         let bearing = bearingBetween(
             startLocation: currentLocation,
            endLocation: location
        )
         let distance: Float = 5
        let originTransform = matrix_identity_float4x4
        // Create a transform with a translation of 5meter away
        //        let translationMatrix = MatrixHelper.translate(
        //            x: 0,
        //            y: 0,
        //            z: distance * -1
       //        )
              let translationMatrix = getTranslationZMatrix(tz: distance * -1) 
      // Rotation matrix theta degrees               
      //        let rotationMatrix = MatrixHelper.rotateAboutY(
      //            degrees: bearing * -1
      //        )
              let rotationMatrix = getRotationYMatrix(angle: Float(bearing * 180 / Double.pi))
              var transformMatrix = simd_mul(rotationMatrix, translationMatrix)
              return simd_mul(originTransform, transformMatrix)
        }
```

Comment: Decent code, but some tips: You don't need `simd_` prefixes for most of these functions/types in Swift. And you can use the `*` operator instead of `simd_mul`. And [you can construct rotation matrices from quaternions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917538/957768) instead of doing the math yourself.

Comment: Mmmm, thanks for a very fruitful comment. Some people get difficulties to understand quaternions, and their meaning, they prefer the more obvious math. Anyway, quaternions are another option.