# How do I rotate an arkit 4x4 matrix around Y using Apple's SIMD library?

Tags: swift, matrix-multiplication, arkit

I am trying to implement some code based on an ARKit demo where someone used this helper function to place a waypoint

```
let rotationMatrix = MatrixHelper.rotateAboutY(
    degrees: bearing * -1
)
```

How can I implement the .rotateAboutY function using the SIMD library and not using GLKit?  To make it easier, I could start from the origin point.

I'm not too handy with the matrix math so a more basic explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with simd directly, but you could just define your own 4x4 rotation matrix (see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html) and then simd_mul to get the answer.

Comment: You can do, just the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to leverage the built-in SIMD library for such operations (at least, with "best" meaning "do the least math yourself") is to express rotations with quaternions and convert to matrices when needed.

1. Construct a `simd_quatf` representing the axis-angle rotation you want to apply.
2. Convert that quaternion to a 4x4 matrix.

You can do that with a one-line call :

```
let rotationMatrix = float4x4(simd_quatf(angle: radians, axis: axis))
```

Expanding to your "rotateAboutY" case:

```
let radians = degreesToRadians(-bearing) // degrees * .pi / 180
let yAxis = float3(0, 1, 0)
let rotationMatrix = float4x4(simd_quatf(angle: radians, axis: yAxis))
```

Of course, once you have a rotation matrix, you can apply it using the `*` or `*=` operator:

```
someNode.simdTransform *= rotationMatrix
```

If you find yourself doing something like this often, you might want to write an extension on `float4x4`.

> <sub>Tip: By the way, in Swift (or C++ or Metal shader language) you don't need the `simd_` prefix on most (but not all) SIMD types and global functions.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The rotation around Y matrix is:

```
| cos(angle) 0 sin(angle)|
|      0    1    0       |
|-sin(angle) 0 cos(angle)|
```

Rotation counter-clockwise around Y:

```
|cos(angle) 0 -sin(angle)|
|    0      1       0    |
|sin(angle) 0  cos(angle)|
```

So, we can easily construct the matrix using simd (*Accelerate Framework*):

```
func makeRotationYMatrix(angle: Float) -> simd_float3x3 {
    let rows = [
        simd_float3(cos(angle), 0, -sin(angle)),
        simd_float3(0, 1, 0),
        simd_float3(-sin(angle), 0, cos(angle))
    ]

    return float3x3(rows: rows)
}
```

The angle here is in radians. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_matrices).